# Adjust label height to height of string

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm making a C# Windows Forms application in which I have a label. This label's size is 100x100 by default*, but I want to automatically increase the label's height so that any string fits in it regardless of its "height". How would I do this? I haven't tried anything myself yet because I don't really have an idea of what to do. I'm just a beginner, after all!

Thanks in advance.

*100x100 is just an example, the real size is different (I'm not sure yet what it'll be)

Comment: checkout the autosize property!

Comment: I know about AutoSize, but wouldn't that just continue on one line as long as there are no \r\n in the string? @DanielA.White

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445780(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: With `AutoSize=true`, set the label's `MaximumSize.Width = 100;`

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find the WordWrap property, but I figured out you could set AutoSize to true and then set MaximumSize for the label. Worked fine. Thanks!

EDIT: @LarsTech Whoops, didn't see your comment yet, that's working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I managed to get what I want by setting the label's MaximumSize property. (Answered by @LarsTech in comments)

Comment: Well it doesn't let me accept my own answer.. Oops.

Comment: You can in a little while but it won't gain you rep.

Answer (score 0):

AutoSize defaults to true - so the default behaviour of the textbox should resize to any font size/content that is in use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the label is located next to a PictureBox, and it extends to the width of the form, centered, so i declared the label like this:

```
Label lblPrompt = new Label()
{
    Text = Message,
    AutoSize = true,        
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
    Location = new Point(picBox.X + picBox.Width + 4, picBox.Y),
    MaximumSize = new Size(form.ClientSize.Width - (picBox.X + picBox.Width) + 8, 0),   
    MinimumSize = new Size(form.ClientSize.Width - (picBox.X + picBox.Width) + 8, 64),
};
```

Having a 0 in the Maximum Height forces the label to autosize-grow only Vertically.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The label control in Windows Forms is a container which accepts your input strings. Therefore, if you do change its initial values it will get to its content size anyways. So, just change its Text Property.
You could try it first.

Answer (score -1):

here's an example code you can use. It uses the AutoSize property.

If you label is called Label1 you can change it like this: 
   Label1.AutoSize = true;
   Label1.Text = "The text in this label is longer than the set size.";

And it will automatically change it.